# R options(digits=2) function changes the total number of digits’ format. Looking for a way to change the digits after decimal point

Tags: r

The `options(digits=2)` changed the total number of digits going forward:

```
> options(digits=3)

> 1.234 

[1] 1.23
> 12.234 

[1] 12.2
> 123.234 

[1] 123
```

Is there any way to change the number formatting such that it changes the digits after decimal point, so with digits_after_decimal=3 the number 1.12345 becomes 1.123 and 123.12345 become 123.123?

I am aware of the functions round or format; however, they just return the result based on parameters whereas options(digits=3) changes all formatting going forward.

Comment: If your goal is to print, you can try `cat(formatC(c(1.23,1.23456,123.1234),format='f',digits=3))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Request for improved "reporting" options in R have a long history, but never have been met with modifications to base-R. It's not possible to change the behavior of the `print.default` function which is what you are using (without knowing so) to do rounding with the flip of an option switch. (You can check that there is no `print.numeric` by using `methods`.) So my advice would be to learn to use `round`, `sprintf` or `formatC` on the items you want rounded. There will be an additional "hitch" in that the  sprintf or formatC results will be a character value and it will display with quotes unless you use `cat` to print,  or set `quote=FALSE` for a `print` call. @digEmAll illustrated 2 of these issues with his suggestion. You may want to look at more "complete" strategies for getting reporting formatting as offered by the various "tables" functions and packages. You can see a wide array of such by searching on the available packages with "table" and "tabular". The ones I have experience with include `htmlTables`, `tabular`, and `xtable` but there are many others and this does not include the `knitr` and `Sweave` options.