# Keep p-value format from emmeans::contrast in one column and a reasonable number of decimal points at other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, decimal-point

I have `option(scipen=999)` in my `.Rprofile` file, and `options(digits = 7)` at the beginning of my `.Rmd`, to accommodate large ratios and a wide range of ratios in my contrast tables.

I want to keep 2 decimal places in the `ratio`, `SE` and `t.ratio` columns, unless the value is too small, and keep the `<.0001` format at the `p.value column`. When the value is too small, in my case, 0.0004, I don't want to round it to 0. I am looking for a sleeker solution than what I have come up with.

Here is the `dataframe` I wanted to edit

```
tab1 <- contrast(model, list("..."), infer = c(F,T)) %>% print(export = T) %>% as.data.frame()
```

while the `print` command makes the output **not** a `dataframe`, keeping the `p.value` format, the `as.data.frame`command allows me to modify other columns later. [Keep p-value format from the `emmeans::joint_tests()` output in a knitted pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909697/keep-p-value-format-from-the-emmeansjoint-tests-output-in-a-knitted-pdf)

```
> dput(tab1)
structure(list(`contrast           ` = c("(2-year) / (3-year)", 
"(2-year) / (4-year)", "(3-year) / (4-year)", "soybean / oat    ", 
"soybean / alfalfa", "soybean / corn   ", "oat / alfalfa    ", 
"oat / corn       ", "alfalfa / corn   "), ratio = c(0.429, 0.286, 
0.668, 0.000388, 0.00323, 0.0331, 8.34, 85.3, 10.2), SE = c(0.2, 
0.127, 0.26, 0.000181, 0.00191, 0.0138, 5.21, 39.8, 6.03), df = c("51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51"), null = c("   1", 
"   1", "   1", "   1", "   1", "   1", "   1", "   1", "   1"
), t.ratio = c(-1.818, -2.829, -1.034, -16.857, -9.728, -8.18, 
3.392, 9.541, 3.944), p.value = c(" 0.1738", " 0.0180", " 0.5588", 
" <.0001", " <.0001", " <.0001", " 0.0071", " <.0001", " 0.0014"
)), row.names = c("X", "X.1", "X.2", "X.3", "X.4", "X.5", "X.6", 
"X.7", "X.8"), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

convert `ratio`, `SE`, and `t.ratio` to numeric:
tab1[,c(2,3,6)] <- sapply(tab1[,c(2,3,6)],as.numeric)

The first `mutate` command rounded the numbers to 4 decimal places to display in non-scientific format and the second `mutate` removed all the trailing zeros in `ratio`, `SE`, and `t.ratio`.

```
tab1_rounded <- tab1 %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 4)) %>%mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.character))`
```

I am not totally satisfied with my `tab1_rounded` because the `soybean/oat` is in scientific form, `4e-04`.  I want `0.0004`, which was what I expected of `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 4))`.

[image]

Using `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, 5))` returned `0.00039`.

I am aware that the `digits =`  command dictates the total number of digits in a column using the largest value in that particular column and can render inconsistent numbers of decimal places, so `round` is recommended instead of trying to mess with `digits` [R options(digits=2) function changes the total number of digits’ format. Looking for a way to change the digits after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387694/r-optionsdigits-2-function-changes-the-total-number-of-digits-format-looking)

Thank you for your attention!!

Comment: Have you tried `options(scipen =999)`

Comment: If this is for print purpose, why not try `tab1 %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ sprintf('%.4f', .)))`

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to copy and paste for all the problematic numbers. This `0.0004` vs. `0.00039` is not the only cell I have to deal with.

Comment: Just nit-picking, but this is not output from `joint_tests()` as the title claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `formattable::comma` with `digits` specified which will also keep the column as `numeric`

```
library(dplyr)
tab1 %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ formattable::comma(., digits = 4)))
    contrast              ratio      SE df null  t.ratio p.value
X   (2-year) / (3-year)  0.4290  0.2000 51    1  -1.8180  0.1738
X.1 (2-year) / (4-year)  0.2860  0.1270 51    1  -2.8290  0.0180
X.2 (3-year) / (4-year)  0.6680  0.2600 51    1  -1.0340  0.5588
X.3   soybean / oat      0.0004  0.0002 51    1 -16.8570  <.0001
X.4   soybean / alfalfa  0.0032  0.0019 51    1  -9.7280  <.0001
X.5   soybean / corn     0.0331  0.0138 51    1  -8.1800  <.0001
X.6   oat / alfalfa      8.3400  5.2100 51    1   3.3920  0.0071
X.7   oat / corn        85.3000 39.8000 51    1   9.5410  <.0001
X.8   alfalfa / corn    10.2000  6.0300 51    1   3.9440  0.0014
```

---

Or convert to `tibble` to do the format printing

```
tab1 %>%
     mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ as.numeric(sprintf('%.4f', .)))) %>% 
     as_tibble
# A tibble: 9 x 7
  `contrast           `   ratio      SE df    null   t.ratio p.value  
  <chr>                   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>    
1 "(2-year) / (3-year)"  0.429   0.2    51    "   1"   -1.82 " 0.1738"
2 "(2-year) / (4-year)"  0.286   0.127  51    "   1"   -2.83 " 0.0180"
3 "(3-year) / (4-year)"  0.668   0.26   51    "   1"   -1.03 " 0.5588"
4 "soybean / oat    "    0.0004  0.0002 51    "   1"  -16.9  " <.0001"
5 "soybean / alfalfa"    0.0032  0.0019 51    "   1"   -9.73 " <.0001"
6 "soybean / corn   "    0.0331  0.0138 51    "   1"   -8.18 " <.0001"
7 "oat / alfalfa    "    8.34    5.21   51    "   1"    3.39 " 0.0071"
8 "oat / corn       "   85.3    39.8    51    "   1"    9.54 " <.0001"
9 "alfalfa / corn   "   10.2     6.03   51    "   1"    3.94 " 0.0014"
```

Comment: Thank you. It gives me `0.0004` but also all the trailing zeros. I did `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ formattable::comma(., digits = 4))) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.character))` and got a warning:  `Registered S3 method overwritten by 'htmlwidgets':
  method           from         
  print.htmlwidget tools:rstudio`

Comment: @hnguyen what is your expected output for 0.0004

Comment: I got 0.0004 but all the trailing zeros at other places, such as 85.3000 and 10.2000. I want 0.0004, 85.3, 10.2, and so on.

Comment: @hnguyen `tab1 %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ as.numeric(sprintf('%.4f', .)))) %>% as_tibble` prints in that way you desired